# Updatable News Section With ASP.NET and XML

Tags: asp.net, xml

im trying todo is when i put something on the xmlTitle.Text(textbox) & xmlContent.Text(textbox) i want my TextXML.xml will be updated, little help please??

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlfile = new XmlDocument();
        xmlfile.Load(Server.MapPath ("~/TestXML.xml"));
        //create element
        XmlElement theNewsTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("news");
        XmlElement theTitleTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("title");
        XmlElement theContentsTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("contents");
        //create text node
        XmlText theTitleText = xmlfile.CreateTextNode(xmlTitle.Text);
        XmlText theContentsText = xmlfile.CreateTextNode(xmlContent.Text);
        //append
        theTitleTag.AppendChild(theTitleText);
        theContentsTag.AppendChild(theContentsText);

        theNewsTag.AppendChild(theTitleTag);
        theNewsTag.AppendChild(theContentsTag);
        //save
        xmlfile.DocumentElement.AppendChild(theNewsTag);
        xmlfile.Save(Server.MapPath ("~/TestXML.xml"));

    }
```

Comment: This is what im trying todo http://bit.ly/Rxfvet but it seems its not C# but its asp.net :(

Comment: it is C#. You use C# or Vb in asp.net . Asp.net is not a language it is a technology.

Comment: Use XmlNode like this `XmlNode theNewsTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("news");
        XmlNode theTitleTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("title");`

Comment: Dim is available in VB and you are using C#.

Comment: Your code is working I checked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working, to test it I create an xml with name TestXml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>

</Data>
```

and aspx code

```
     <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="Write XML"  
    onclick="button_Click" />
 <asp:TextBox  ID="xmlContent" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="xmlTitle" runat="server" />
```

and button Click event code

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XmlDocument xmlfile = new XmlDocument();
    xmlfile.Load(Server.MapPath("~/TestXML.xml"));
    //create element
    XmlElement theNewsTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("news");
    XmlElement theTitleTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("title");
    XmlElement theContentsTag = xmlfile.CreateElement("contents");
    //create text node
    XmlText theTitleText = xmlfile.CreateTextNode(xmlTitle.Text);
    XmlText theContentsText = xmlfile.CreateTextNode(xmlContent.Text);
    //append
    theTitleTag.AppendChild(theTitleText);
    theContentsTag.AppendChild(theContentsText);

    theNewsTag.AppendChild(theTitleTag);
    theNewsTag.AppendChild(theContentsTag);
    //save
    xmlfile.DocumentElement.AppendChild(theNewsTag);
    xmlfile.Save(Server.MapPath("~/TestXML.xml"));


}
```

and I got the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <news>
   <title>second1</title>
   <contents>first1</contents>
 </news>
</Data>
```

Comment: it's working now thanks again :) i dont have any onclick xD sorry for troubling you